# Double view render in routers

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        'notes': 'showNotes',
        "note/:noteId":       "openNote"
    },

    showNotes: function() {
        new app.NotesView;
    },

    openNote: function(noteId) {
        var NotesCollection = new app.NotesCollection();
        NotesCollection.fetch();

        var view = new app.NotesView({
            currentModel : NotesCollection.get(noteId)
        })

    }
});
```

Here the problem comes when I navigate to domain.com/#notes every time I navigate there a double view occurs, and any event get's fired multiple times.

Comment: Can you show the code for view in question.. Also it is a better idea if you have a separate views for a single note and all the notes together. That way your code can be more modularized

Comment: I already have a separate view for each note, The problem as @Civ stated is that each time I create a new view in the router, an new event handler is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because every time you go there, you create a new view (the old view still exists). Instead, can you just create the view once and on showNotes, you call render?

Also, as a side note, fetch() is an asynchronous call so you have to wait until data is fetched by passing in a callback (success function) and doing your calculations there.

Something like this:

```
var notesView = new app.NotesView;

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes:{
    'notes': 'showNotes',
    "note/:noteId":       "openNote"
},

showNotes: function() {
    notesView.render(); // or append notesView.$el into the dom somewhere
},

openNote: function(noteId) {
    var NotesCollection = new app.NotesCollection();
    NotesCollection.fetch({
        success: function(){
            notesView.setModel(NotesCollection.get(noteId); // make this method youself
        }
    });
}
```

});